# Search in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a list of products and I want to search any word by names in the list, using NodeJS.

This is my code now:

```
router.get('/products', function (req, res) {

  var size = parseInt(req.query.pageSize);

  if (req.query.pageNumber == 1) {
    var page = 0;
  } else {
    var page = parseInt(req.query.pageNumber) * req.query.pageSize - req.query.pageSize;
  }

  Product.count()
    .exec(function (err, numberProducts) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: 'Can not download this list'
        })
      } else {
        Product.find().skip(page).limit(size)
          .exec(function (err, products) {
            if (err) {
              res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Can not download this list'
              })
            } else {
              res.json({ "count": numberProducts, "products": products })

            }
          })
      }
    })
});
```

So in my HTML code I have to create an input with ng-model, whose value will be sent to the controller later, and then send to nodeJS by http.get with word. (input will work on the onChange directive). What should I do next?

Comment: What to do next? (1) Consider fixing your error handling, returning a `404` (not found) upon DB errors seems not quite right. (2) Write a query for your problem e.g. `{ text: { $regex: '.*' + text + '.*' } }` (have a look at the MongoDB doc. for details).

Comment: Okej, thanks, what is $regex?? and, can I make if in product.find() ??

Comment: (1) Look at the docs, it's explained well. (2) Don't understand this question.